# Change start and end index inside filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, filter, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a filter which will help me filter out the results from an array based on certain index.

```
const newArr = oldArr.filter((item, index) => for(index === selectedIndex; index < selectedIndex + 2; index ++) {
return this.createOptions(item, index, selectedItem))
};
```

I get selectedIndex from an event handler in my code. How do I write such a case?

Comment: That's invalid syntax. You can't `return` a `for`, so it can't be there in an arrow function. (also, your initializer of `index === selectedIndex` looks suspect)

Comment: yes, I know! But how do I make it syntactically correct to support the logic mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your (pseudo) code what are you trying to do. My best guess is that you want to get an item from an array at specified index:

```
// get item at position `selectedIndex` in array
const item = oldArr[selectedIndex]

// do whatever you need with the item
this.createOptions(item, index, selectedItem)
```